# Replacing remote git repo with local version having lost .git

Tags: git, github, webhooks, pelican

I'm setting up automatic deployment of my Pelican blog using the newly-released [Dropbox webhooks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/90/announcing-dropbox-webhooks).  Every time I change a file in Dropbox, it `POST`s to my Heroku app, which does the following:

1. Downloads the content from Dropbox
2. Runs `pelican` over the new content to reproduce the blog.  The output is to the local clone of my Github Pages repo.

   - This deletes all of the content that currently exists in the repo and replaces it with the newly generated blog.  **Unfortunately, this also deletes the .git directory.**
3. I've lost my `.git/`, so I run `git init` and readd the remote.
4. I run `git pull origin master` to sync them up.
5. Tracks all changes, new files, and deletions using `git add -A .`.
6. Commits, pushes to Github.

The problem is facing is in Step 4, when I run `git pull`, it pulls all of the original information from the repo--including the files I want deleted.  E.g., if I delete  a post, it's properly deleted from the repo when I run `pelican` and it deletes the whoel folder and regenerates the blog without the file--but then that file reappears when I run `git pull`.   I am not able to track which files are deleted because I lose my git history when `.git/` is deleted when I run `pelican`.

At the end of the day, all I want to do is to run `pelican`, replace the entire contents of the repo, and then add all of the changes/deletsion/additions and then push the repo to Github.  I will never need information on what's currently in the repo, so running `git reset` wouldn't be a problem for me, if helps.  How can I do this?

Comment: To ameliorate the damage, try relocating .git:  `mv .git ../somewhere/outside; echo git: ../somewhere/outside >.git`.  That way, when `pelican` starts getting careless, just redoing the echo will fix it.  Sounds like the real solution is to make `pelican` stop deleting things you don't want deleted, though.

Comment: Agreed, but I was hoping to learn a git way to do it.

Comment: The goal was ease of use for creating article posts, hence I wanted to be able to simply drop new Markdown files in my Dropbox, like Scriptogr.am.  The reason for git is simply that the blog is hosted on GitHub pages, which requires me to use git to push the final static site output.  I don't think using dropbox + git in this scenario would be problematic, and indeed the problem above is completely unrelated to dropbox.

Comment: It sounds like the actual problem is "how to stop pelican from deleting the .git folder" - The rest of the info in the question isn't really that relevant. Looks like that's a [known "feature"](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/574)

Comment: That wasn't the question, I know how to do that--but it ended up being the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seemed to be no way to do what I was trying to do in git, what I ended up doing was setting pelican's `DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` setting to `False` and then as part of my Fabric script running

```
rm -rf *
```

myself instead, which ignores dot-prefix files and directories, and therefore left `.git/` alone.  Then I could regenerate and add the new content to the repository, commit, and push without issue.